# Change Label Color in combo chart

Tags: qliksense

I have a combo chart that looks like this:
[image]

I want to change label color of line chart. I haven't found any options in the properties panel. So, I tried changing it with a new theme. Below is the part that I have added to theme.json.

```
"comboChart": {
   "label": {
       "value":{
           "color": "#c92e00"
               }
            }
}
```

Now my problem is that I can not access the line labels specifically and the code addresses all labels including bar labels.

Can anyone help me to find access to only line labels?

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this question int he Qlik Community?

https://community.qlik.com/t5/App-Development/Value-labels-themes/td-p/1528490

Looks like you need the "name" property inside comboChart

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I have seen this question before and it doesn't answer my question. I want to change the color of the value of a label not its name.